# Dataset for Device fingerprints?

Tags: data-request, internet

For research purposes, I'm looking for [Device Fingerprint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_fingerprint) datasets.

A device might be a browser, a headless browser or even a network library capable of HTTP traffic.

A device fingerprint might include any information regrading the device, from its network behavior to its javascript and plugin extracted information (screen resolution, timezone, etc..)

Comment: Did you by any chance manage to find a dataset with active fingerprinting data?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. Our conclusion was that we'll need to generate it ourselves, using an inner enterprise traffic or an outer internet honeypot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[Fingerbank](http://fingerbank.org/)**

> Fingerbank accurately determines what kind of device is connected on a network based on its MAC [External] address, its DHCP [External] fingerprint and its User-Agent [External].
>
> **When you query the Fingerbank database using the API, if this combination of data is unknown to Fingerbank, it will be automatically added to the Fingerbank database.**

Access options:

- [Query the fingerprints online](https://fingerbank.inverse.ca/)
- [Download the data as an SQLite database](https://fingerbank.inverse.ca/download)
- [Public API](https://fingerbank.inverse.ca/api_doc) (requires registration)

[License](http://fingerbank.org/license.html)

- The Fingerbank data is licensed under the [Open Database License](http://opendatacommons.org/licenses/odbl/1.0/)

Comment: Thanks @philshem! Fingerbank seems like a solid dataset for passive fingerprinting. Do you know any datasets with active fingerprinting data (like javascript and plugin extracted information)?

Answer (score 2):

Researched in that also a long time.

I discovered that [fingerprint-suite](https://github.com/apify/fingerprint-suite) contains some, allready analyzed data (for example [`/packages/header-generator/src/data_files/browser-helper-file.json`](https://github.com/apify/fingerprint-suite/blob/master/packages/header-generator/src/data_files/browser-helper-file.json)), but couldn't find any raw samples.

Also, if you're looking for a solution to emulate fingerprints using Python, [Selenium-Profiles](https://github.com/kaliiiiiiiiii/Selenium-Profiles/discussions/33) might help you:)

Comment: what about the zip files under that same path you reference as well as https://github.com/apify/fingerprint-suite/blob/master/packages/fingerprint-generator/src/data_files/fingerprint-network-definition.zip?

Comment: @David Uh yep that might be useful as well

Answer (score 0):

In terms of browser based user agent & manufacturer device model fingerprints, there are quite a few around but you have to consolidate it all yourself if not using paid lookup service options to simplify your work. It would be nice to have a single central repository.

https://github.com/N0taN3rd/userAgentLists

https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/1727131?hl=en

https://storage.googleapis.com/play_public/supported_devices.html

https://github.com/SeparateRecords/apple_device_identifiers

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204683

https://github.com/jtorvald/AD2C

https://blacktop.github.io/ipsw/docs/guides/device_list

https://github.com/blacktop/ipsw/raw/master/pkg/info/data/ipsw_db.json

https://gist.github.com/adamawolf/3048717

http://www.tera-wurfl.com/explore/search.php?action=browse

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201300

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201862

https://everymac.com/ultimate-mac-lookup

https://developer.amazon.com/docs/fire-tablets/ft-identifying-tablet-devices.html

https://developer.amazon.com/docs/fire-tablets/ft-user-agent-strings.html

https://developer.amazon.com/docs/fire-tv/identify-amazon-fire-tv-devices.html

https://developer.amazon.com/docs/fire-tv/user-agent-strings.html

https://whatismyphone.net/vendors/amazon?page=2

https://deviceatlas.com/blog/list-smart-tv-user-agent-strings

https://deviceatlas.com/blog/list-of-user-agent-strings

https://deviceatlas.com/device-data/devices/samsung